# Pyspark: spark data frame column width configuration in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, jupyter-notebook

I have the following code in Jupyter Notebook:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', 80)
my_df.select('field_1','field_2').show()
```

I want to increase the column width so I could see the full value of `field_1` and `field_2`. I know we can use  `pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', 80)` for pandas data frame, but it doesn't seem to work for spark data frame.

Is there a way to increase the column width for the spark data frame like what we did for pandas data frame? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried registering it as a temp table and then using the SQL context to show it as a table instead?

Answer (score 20):

I don't think you can set a specific width, but this will ensure your data is not cutoff no matter the size

```
my_df.select('field_1','field_2').show(10, truncate = False)
```

Comment: I got the error: show() got an unexpected keyword argument 'truncate' if I use the code above. Any idea?

Comment: Hmm, try without the truncate= part eg `show(False)`

Comment: I then got the error: Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o105.showString. Trace: ...

Comment: Everytime I've used it, I have also specified the number of records to show (`show(5,truncate = False)`), but the api documentation say that the other ways should work. Maybe try this way?

Comment: it didn't recognize truncate at all (show() got an unexpected keyword argument 'truncate'), did u import anything?

Comment: is my_df a pandas dataframe or a spark dataframe? Can you show how it was created

Answer (score 1):

This should give you what you want

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', 80)
my_df.select('field_1','field_2').limit(100).toPandas()
```

Comment: The data is big, I can't convert it toPandas(). I need to do it in pyspark data frame

Comment: Yes but when you do show() it all goes to your notebook too. If the data is big you have to limit it for display. And I this is why put here .limit(100) so only first 100 records will show in the notebook. You can remove it and you get all records.

Answer (score 1):

Both the following will work

```
my_df.select('field1','field2').show(10,False)

my_df.select('field1','field2').show(False)
```

Answer (score 0):

you have just to add a 0 or False after the comma in show() , like below :

```
my_df.select('field1','field2').show(10,0) 
or
my_df.select('field1','field2').show(10,False)
```

Best,